# WSO2 emm app management for windows mobile

Tags: java, windows, wso2, xap, wso2-iot

Good day

I am looking to use the wso2 emm on windows devices.

1) How can I add a XAP application on WSO2 store?
2) how to parse the manifest.xml file inside a XAP package?

Answer (score 0):

Currently WSO2 EMM does not support windows app management and neither does WSO2 App manager

Comment: I completed adding compatibility of windows phone application on Store and Publisher. you didn't help but thank you for your comment